# passing data to spreadsheet together apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

this two function works together in on HTML code i want to append data to last row in spreadsheet together
i tried to get last row and column but ssume if delayed alittle bit it will replace in another record , so how can i pass all outputs so it can be appended in on row.

[**result i'm seeking**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3KDX.png)

Html Code

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
        <p id = "status"></p>
        <a id = "map-link" target="_blank"></a>
  <p id = "1"></p>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (datareturned) {

        alert(datareturned)
        $('#1').text(datareturned)
      }).getuser_email();
  });
          function geoFindMe() {
    
            const status = document.querySelector('#status');
            const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');
          
            mapLink.href = '';
            mapLink.textContent = '';
          
            function success(position) {
              
              const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
              const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
             
              google.script.run.saveCoordinates(latitude,longitude);
                             
              status.textContent = '';
              mapLink.href = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/' + `${latitude}\/${longitude}`;
              mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
            }
    
            function error() {
              status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
            }
    
            if(!navigator.geolocation) {
              status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
            } else {
              status.textContent = 'Locating…';
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
            }
    
          }
    
             document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('load', geoFindMe);
                window.onload = geoFindMe
           </script>
          </body>
    </html>
```

```
    function saveCoordinates(latitude,longitude){
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const rowContents = [latitude+","+longitude];
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
      sheet.appendRow(rowContents);
      
    }
function getuser_email(){
   const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
     return email;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your HTML so I've made a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function js_SaveCoordinates(latitude,longitude) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
          function(email) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
              function (results) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(results));
              }
            ). saveCoordinates(email,latitude,longitude);
          }
        ).getuser_email();
      }
      (function () { js_SaveCoordinates(1,2); }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Code.gs:

```
function getuser_email() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return email;
}

function saveCoordinates(email,latitude,longitude) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowContents = [[email,latitude,longitude]];  // 2 dimensional array with 1 row
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,rowContents.length,rowContents[0].length).setValues(rowContents);
  return { email: email, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude };
}
```

Comment: Hi the Wiz , appreciate your reply , sorry for this i considered it won;t be the big matter 
i edited the post including HTML Code

Comment: i will appreciate to tell me how can i do it with the above HTML and gs file , thanks in advance for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I thought your question was how to make both functions respond synchronously.  You mentioned delay which I thought was delay in getting data from one or the other function.

To put the latitude and longitude into a new row you could simply do this.

```
function saveCoordinates(latitude,longitude){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rowContents = [latitude,longitude];
  sheet.appendRow(rowContents);
}
```

Comment: hi , thanks alot for your help , your first answer worked well with me ♥